# Log in works fine, but now no functions can be called

Tags: javascript, facebook, function, authentication, header

Here is my code that starts right below the opening body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
alert("made it into the script");
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : '360348567392858', // App ID from the App Dashboard
  channelUrl : 'http://chrisvanhorne.com/users/erosas/final/channel.html', // Channel      File for x-domain communication
  status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
  cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         // User logged into FB and authorized
            testAPI();
            document.getElementById('fb-logout').style.display = 'block';
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // User logged into FB but not authorized
            login();
      } else {
        // User not logged into FB
            login();
            document.getElementById('fb-logout').style.display = 'block';
      }
     });

};

    function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            alert("made it to login");
            testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
}

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
}   

 // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
 // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
 // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
 // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
 (function(d, debug){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document, /*debug*/ false));


</script>
```

The log in function works fine, but afterwards no calls can be made to functions within this script tag. Not only that, but oddly enough no `<script>`'s with javascript in them work at all after the Facebook script code. None of the debug alert() functions are called and no calls are made(that I can tell to Facebook).

Some possible issues I've considered, but am unsure about:

1. I use php to call the header and footer and this code is in the header, not too sure if that affects anything loading-wise
2. The domain that I access this through is password protected, that is, when I navigate to this url a window pops up and I need to log in to see the page, not too sure if that messes with Facebook's SDK/servers
3. Maybe there's a fairly obvious solution that I am not seeing

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am currently going crazy trying to figure this out, thanks!

Comment: did you put it through a javascript debugger and find an error?

Comment: Ah yes, it gave me a "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined " error, I apologize if this is a really simply fix, I didn't see anything on the Facebook Developers page and I am new at the Facebook SDK

Comment: i've never used the facebook stuff but you are probably missing an include. maybe there is a facebook url that you need to include before you run your code

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable, it was in part due because the code wasn't waiting for the init function to complete and because there were "bad" javascript tags in the head(not shown) that ended as:  rather than . Easy fix, will search harder for answers next time